# How to Setup Mercurial Server In Ubuntu To Serve 60 repositories

Tags: apache, mercurial, mercurial-server

I want to have around 60 repositories of projects and I want to serve them from a dedicated remote server(ubuntu) with the help of mercurial-server so that all my developers will be able to update their changes. I have followed [this articl](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories)e in order to do that but I am not clearly able to understand. I have some following questions:

1. How to install mercurial-server? Does all repo will be controlled by "hg user" (whose directory is at server/home/hg) and does the user will be automatically created during installation of mercurial server(like mysql) ?
2. Do I need to install mercurial client(i.e. apt-get install mercurial) on my remote server? I know the client side must install `mercurial` to push/pull repo to/from remote mercurial server. What exactly the diffence between `mercurial` and `mercurial-server` ?

**Note:**
Please provide me a abstract (yet understandable) steps to setup mercurial server in order to serve some project from my dedicated ubuntu server if possible.

**(i.e. prerequisites>install>setup>authentication for push/pull>web interface).**

Comment: I've voted to move this to stackoverflow since it's about large-scale operations not individual user tool use, but please do make sure you understand that "mercurial-server" isn't _the_ mercurial server.  It's a 3rd party piece of software.  Developers will only need the 'mercurial' package and the server needs only the 'mercurial' package.  You'll also need a webserver (like apache or nginx) and an wsgi container (like mod_wsgi or gunicorn). The instructions on the Mercurial wiki's PublishingRepositories page are quite good -- they're just not software development Q&A.

Comment: How can I install latest mercurial. I have tried `apt-get install mercurial` but the older version is got installed. I need to install it system wide

Comment: [Sharing Mercurial repositories with mercurial-server](http://dev.lshift.net/paul/mercurial-server/docbook.html) is the "official" guide for setting mercurial-server up.

Comment: If you don't need SSH i would recommend setting up [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org) for hosting repositories.
It'll provide you with an easy to use web interface for managing permissions.

Comment: Please consider answering the question rather than giving alternatives.